# How can I perform a RegEx match in Twig?

Tags: templating, regex

Is it possible to perform a RegEx match on a string in Twig?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
{% set string = "This is **string**. **wer**  qewr **234**" %}
{% set match  = string.matches(/([*][*])(.*)([*][*])/g) %}
```

Comment: This question is a better fit the on StackOverflow site.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl now?

Comment: I believe you'd have to extend twig for this. [This](https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions#pcre) looks like it has what you'd need, specifically the `preg_get_all`. If you're trying to bold that text though, there's a [`markdown`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#markdown-or-md) filter that can do that for you.

Comment: Yes, your edit makes the question relevant to Craft.

Comment: Here's a preg_replace implementation in a Craft plugin: https://github.com/low/low_regex/. This should give you a framework to build what you need. Nice if the 'on hold' comes off your original question, and good fortune.

Comment: To open the question we need one more vote to reopen it. It's beside the edit and flag link.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently Twig uses [regular expressions](https://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) only with [Comparisons](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons):

```
{% if string matches '{^[\d\.]+$}' %}
    Do Stuff
{% endif %}
```

Craft itself currently doesn't have any custom Twig [filters](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters) or [functions](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions) either.

But there are third-party plugins which might help you:

- [Twig PCRE Filters](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigPCRE)
- [Low Regex](https://github.com/low/low_regex/)

Comment: As of Craft 2.2, the `replace` filter [now supports regular expressions...](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace)

Answer (score 5):

This works for me just fine:

```
{# Removes all characters other than numbers and + #}
{{ profile.phone|replace('/[^0-9+]/', '') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answers for 2023 using Craft CMS 4

**For simple find and replace:** you can just use the [replace filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#replace), it accepts RegEx now.

**For more complicated lookups:** If you're looking to just add Craft CMS filters in general or use PHP filters, like `preg_match_all()` you can install the [Twig Toolbox plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/twig-toolbox?craft4), create the file `config/twig-toolbox.php` with the following code to enable the filter or add more as needed:

```
<?php return [
    'filters' => [
        'preg_match_all' => function(string $subject, string $pattern): array {
            preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
            return $matches;
        },
    ],
    'functions' => [],
    'globals' => [],
    'tests' => [],
];
```

Please note, the above filter is a basic version of the actual `preg_match_all`, see the [full documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and adapt as you see fit.