# Use regex in replace filter

Tags: regex, replace

any idea why this: `%20AND%20foo%3A%22(.+?)%22` won't match this: `%20AND%20foo%3A%22some random string of characters%22` in the Twig `|replace` filter?

If i do this:

```
{% set foo = '%20AND%20foo%3A%22some random string of characters%22' %}
{% set bar = '%20AND%20foo%3A%22(.+?)%22' %}
{{ foo |replace(bar, 'replaced') }}
{# OR THIS #}
{{ foo |replace((bar), 'replaced') }}
```

The result is `foo`. Nothing gets replaced. I'd expect the result to be the string "replaced". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [As of Craft v2.2](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2579), the replace filter now supports regex:

> The replace filter now supports regular expressions, by setting the first argument to a string that begins and ends with forward slashes, e.g. '/foo/'.

So this should work by adding forward slashes.

```
{% set bar = '/%20AND%20foo%3A%22(.+?)%22/' %}
```

I think this is particular to Craft and not native to the Twig replace filter.

---

<del>I don't think the [Twig replace filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) will allow for regex matches.</del>

[According to this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/228/how-can-i-perform-a-regex-match-in-twig), Twig only uses regular expressions with Comparisons.

But there are third-party plugins which might work:

- [Twig PCRE Filters](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigPCRE)
- [Low Regex](https://github.com/low/low_regex/)

Comment: Got it sorted with Low Regex. Thanks for the hint! I was somehow under the impression that the |replace filter can do this.

Comment: As pointed out by Low, [Craft's replace filter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) does now support regex.